# Create array from selected checkbox values

Tags: php, arrays, forms, loops

I have a bunch of checkboxes each with a unique name and value using $_POST method. How can I put the selected values into an array? I started using a for loop, but I don't know how to call only one value at a time or determine whether it has been selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckarray[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckarray[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckarray[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="mycheckarray[]" value="4" />
```

Check boxes 2 and 4, then at the server side, if you `print_r($_POST['mycheckarray']);`, you will get something like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => 2
  [1] => 4
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a group of checkboxes.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup[]" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_0" />Checkbox 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup[]" value="checkbox" id="CheckboxGroup1_1" />Checkbox 2</label>
</form>
```

And after that u can use it as you like. `print_r($_POST[CheckboxGroup]);`